# Doctrine : how to set value to null instead entity

Tags: php, doctrine, zend-framework3

I have a problem with my Doctrine Entity.

In my module, I have a history to list actions performed by users.

During the process, I use a ManyToOne relation of my Entity towards herself.

When I update an item in my database, I use "setGain()" to refer this result to another, but if I want to cancel an action from user I need to set as null the value of setGain(), but Doctrine doesn't accept it and return :

```php
PHP Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Paris\Entity\Historique::setGain() must be an instance of Paris\Entity\Historique, null given
```

My Entity is :

```php
<?php

namespace Paris\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Historique
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="paris__historique")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Historique {
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_historique", type="integer", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id_historique;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_jol", type="integer", length=11, precision=0, scale=0, nullable=true, unique=false)
     */
    private $id_jol;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="action", type="string", length=50, precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     */
    private $action;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="detail", type="text", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=true, unique=false)
     */
    private $detail;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Paris\Entity\Historique")
      * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_gain", referencedColumnName="id_historique", nullable=true)
     * })
     */
    private $id_gain;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Paris\Entity\Parieur")
      * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_participant", referencedColumnName="id_participant", nullable=true)
     * })
     */
    private $id_participant;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Paris\Entity\Concours")
      * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_concours", referencedColumnName="id_concours", nullable=true)
     * })
     */
    private $id_concours;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Paris\Entity\Periode")
      * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_periode", referencedColumnName="id_periode", nullable=true)
     * })
     */
    private $id_periode;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Paris\Entity\Paris")
      * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_paris", referencedColumnName="id_paris", nullable=true)
     * })
     */
    private $id_paris;

     /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Paris\Entity\Mise")
      * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_mise", referencedColumnName="id_mise", nullable=true)
     * })
     */
    private $id_mise;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_historique", type="integer", length=11, precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     */
    private $date_historique;


    public function getIdHistorique() {
        return $this->id_historique;
    }

    public function setIdJol($idJol) {
        $this->id_jol = $idJol;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIdJol() {
        return $this->id_jol;
    }

    public function setAction($action) {
        $this->action = $action;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAction() {
        return $this->action;
    }

    public function getGain() {
        return $this->id_gain;
    }

    public function setGain(\Paris\Entity\Historique $id_gain) {
        $this->id_gain = $id_gain;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setDetail($detail) {
        $this->detail = $detail;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDetail() {
        return $this->detail;
    }

    public function setParieur(\Paris\Entity\Parieur $id_participant) {
        $this->id_participant = $id_participant;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getParieur() {
        return $this->id_participant;
    }

    public function setConcours(\Paris\Entity\Concours $id_concours) {
        $this->id_concours = $id_concours;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getConcours() {
        return $this->id_concours;
    }

    public function setPeriode(\Paris\Entity\Periode $id_periode) {
        $this->id_periode = $id_periode;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getPeriode() {
        return $this->id_periode;
    }

    public function setPari(\Paris\Entity\Paris $id_paris) {
        $this->id_paris = $id_paris;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getPari() {
        return $this->id_paris;
    }

    public function setmise(\Paris\Entity\Mise $id_mise) {
        $this->id_mise = $id_mise;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getMise() {
        return $this->id_mise;
    }

    public function setDate($dateHistorique) {
        $this->date_historique = $dateHistorique;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDate() {
        return $this->date_historique;
    }
}
```

In my database, the associated field is correctly set to Null by default and Nullable.

Can you help me ? ^^

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define `setGain` as:

```
public function setGain(?\Paris\Entity\Historique $id_gain) {
    $this->id_gain = $id_gain;
    return $this;
}
```

`?` in front of class typehint allows to pass `null` as an argument.

Another option is:

```
public function setGain(\Paris\Entity\Historique $id_gain = null) {
    $this->id_gain = $id_gain;
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: thank you, the second option worked ! with the first, my Entity is considered corrupt.